# Rounded rectangle with mid arrow on each side

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to draw a rectangle with rounded angles and with an arrow in the middle of each side. Googling, I found this code to get a "mid arrow", but it gives me back an error ("Dimension too large [...]") when I start debugging

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.markings}

\tikzset{
% style to apply some styles to each segment of a path
on each segment/.style={
    decorate,
    decoration={
        show path construction,
        moveto code={},
        lineto code={
            \path [#1]
            (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
        },
        curveto code={
            \path [#1] (\tikzinputsegmentfirst)
            .. controls
            (\tikzinputsegmentsupporta) and (\tikzinputsegmentsupportb)
            ..
            (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
        },
        closepath code={
            \path [#1]
            (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
        },
    },
},
% style to add an arrow in the middle of a path
mid arrow/.style={postaction={decorate,decoration={
            markings,
            mark=at position .5 with {\arrow[#1]{stealth}}
}}},
}

\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [thick, rounded corners=2pt, postaction={on each segment={mid 
    arrow=black}}] (0.1,0.1) -- (0.1,0.9) -- (0.9,0.9) -- (0.9,0.1) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I managed to fix the problem just by increasing the size of the rectangle (I striclty need the dimensions to be those). Another problem is that in the final picture I get arrows on the corner too like this

[image]

I just want to obtain a rectangle like one of these

[image]
[image]

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you add the arrow to all segments. You may want to add it only to the straight ones.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.markings}
\newcounter{flipflop}
\tikzset{
% style to apply some styles to each segment of a path
on each straight segment/.style={
    decorate,
    decoration={
        show path construction,
        moveto code={},
        lineto code={
            \path [#1]
            (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
        },
        curveto code={
            \path  (\tikzinputsegmentfirst)
            .. controls
            (\tikzinputsegmentsupporta) and (\tikzinputsegmentsupportb)
            ..
            (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
        },
        closepath code={
            \path 
            (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
        },
    },
},
set flipflop/.code=\setcounter{flipflop}{#1},
on each other straight segment/.style={
    decorate,
    decoration={
        show path construction,
        moveto code={},
        lineto code={\stepcounter{flipflop}
            \path \ifodd\value{flipflop} [#1]\fi
            (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
        },
        curveto code={
            \path  (\tikzinputsegmentfirst)
            .. controls
            (\tikzinputsegmentsupporta) and (\tikzinputsegmentsupportb)
            ..
            (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
        },
        closepath code={
            \path 
            (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
        },
    },
},
% style to add an arrow in the middle of a path
mid arrow/.style={postaction={decorate,decoration={
            markings,
            mark=at position .5 with {\arrow[#1]{stealth}}
}}},
}

\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [thick, rounded corners=2pt, postaction={on each straight segment={mid 
    arrow=black}}] (0.1,0.1) -- (0.1,0.9) -- (0.9,0.9) -- (0.9,0.1) -- cycle;
  \begin{scope}[xshift=1.5cm]
    \draw [thick, rounded corners=2pt, postaction={set flipflop=0,on each other straight segment={mid 
    arrow=black}}] (0.1,0.1) -- (0.1,0.9) -- (0.9,0.9) -- (0.9,0.1) -- cycle;
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[xshift=3cm]
    \draw [thick, rounded corners=2pt, postaction={set flipflop=1,on each other straight segment={mid 
    arrow=black}}] (0.1,0.1) -- (0.1,0.9) -- (0.9,0.9) -- (0.9,0.1) -- cycle;
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One more suggestion:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}
\tikzset{
myarrow/.style={
  draw,thick,
  single arrow,
  text width=16pt,
%  fill=white
  },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[arrowed/.style={inner sep=6pt,path picture={
\draw[-latex,#1] ([xshift=2pt,yshift=-2pt]path picture bounding box.north west)
-- ([xshift=-2pt,yshift=-2pt]path picture bounding box.north east);
\draw[-latex,#1] ([xshift=-2pt,yshift=-2pt]path picture bounding box.north east)
-- ([xshift=-2pt,yshift=2pt]path picture bounding box.south east);
\draw[-latex,#1] ([xshift=-2pt,yshift=2pt]path picture bounding box.south east)
-- ([xshift=2pt,yshift=2pt]path picture bounding box.south west);
\draw[-latex,#1] ([xshift=2pt,yshift=-2pt]path picture bounding box.north west)
-- ([xshift=-2pt,yshift=-2pt]path picture bounding box.north east);
\draw[-latex,#1] ([xshift=2pt,yshift=2pt]path picture bounding box.south west)
-- ([xshift=2pt,yshift=-2pt]path picture bounding box.north west);
}}]
\node[arrowed] at (0,0) {some text};
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{2pc}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
   \node [draw,rectangle,minimum size=8pc](r){};
   \node[myarrow,rotate=90] at (r.west){};
   \node[myarrow] at (r.north){};
 \end{tikzpicture}%

\end{document}
```

[image]